# How to kill an android app from task manager?

Tags: android

I have a question with android apps.

"How to kill an android app from task manager?". I have tried `System.exit(0)`, `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());` and `finish()` but they only stop app and don't kill app from task manager. Please tell me how to do that.

**UPDATED:**
I used `finishAffinity()` to clear app from task manager and `System.exit(0)` to stop activity, it looks like fine for my problem.

Comment: where you used these code in activity life cycle?

Answer (score 2):

I based my solution on guest's above, as well as gilsaints88's comments below (for Android L compatibility):

Add this activity to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.ExitActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"/>
```

Then create a class ExitActivity.java:

```
public class ExitActivity extends Activity{
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
        finishAndRemoveTask();
    }
    else{
        finish();
    }
}

public static void exitApplication(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExitActivity.class);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Then whenever you want to force close your application and remove it from the recent's list, call:

```
ExitActivity.exitApplication(context);
```

This solution works for me instead of declaring android:excludeFromRecents="true" because I want the user to be able to see the app in the recents list UNTIL the point where my app triggers closing the app programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems to be running fine with VERSION > 21 but my version >=15.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(context, StartActivity.class);
int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, mPendingIntentId,    mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
System.exit(0);
```